# Homomorphisms of group $\mathbb{Z}$ to itself send even integers to even integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, integers

Since any homomorphism $f$ of additive group $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ is of form $f(x)=a*x$, for some integer $a$, we conclude that $f(2x)=2ax \in 2\mathbb{Z}$, which means $f$ sends even integers to even integers. 
Am I right?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, you are :)

Comment: Even if you don't know this result: $f(2x)=f(x+x)=f(x)+f(x)=2f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks! @57Jimmy